# How to print result from sql result?

Tags: python

I use Select query in mysql and I would like to get records using python.
client_start is SELECT query

```sql
  client_start = con.execute("SELECT DISTINCT `clients_agreements`.`date_start` , `buildings`.`id` , `buildings`.`street` , `buildings`.`street_nr` , `clients`.`building_id` , `clients_agreements`.`user_id` FROM `clients_agreements` LEFT JOIN `buildings` On `clients_agreements`.`user_id` = `buildings`.`id` LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id` WHERE `date_start` = (CURRENT_DATE)") #SELECT ID CLIENT QUERY
```

```py
for row in client_start:
    streets = row[2]
    house_nr = row[3]
    message = str(streets) + " / " + str(house_nr)
 msg = 'Subject: {0}\n\n{1}'.format(subject,message).encode('utf-8').strip()
```

When i use print into loop I get two result(what is good) but when i use print after loop i get only one result. How to print all result after loop? I can't use arrays because I would like to send it in email. I want to send all records

Comment: Effectively, you can't. `message` et al. get overwritten on each loop and you get the last value once you're out of the loop. If your objective is just to print the results then put your `print` inside the loop itself

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because there isn't enough detail.  What is `client_start`, and how is it created?  What do you mean by "after loop I only get one result"?  Give us a complete code example that we can actually run ourselves, and be specific about _how_ the output of that code isn't what you want.

Comment: `print()` is very rarely useful in programs for loops like this. If you have objectives beyond just printing values then there are plenty of ways to handle things differently. Likely you want to use `.fetchall()`, which will return a list that can be dissected into individual values, but you say that you want to avoid lists. I think perhaps your issue stems from not understanding list indexing rather than the email issue.

Comment: I add details, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

As @roganjosh said, each time through the loop you're throwing away the previous contents of `message`.

You can address this in two ways:

Whatever you're doing with `message` -- printing, sending an email, writing to a file, etc. -- do it *inside* the loop, while you have the current value.

Or, if you need to collect all the values and then handle them all at once, save them in a list:

```
messages = []
for row in client_start:
    streets = row[2]
    house_nr = row[3]
    message = str(streets) + " / " + str(house_nr)
    messages.append(message)
# now handle the list of messages
```